# Problem in editing EEPROM of MLX90614ESF sensor , pic 18f4620 , I2C communication

Tags: pic, i2c, infrared, eeprom

I want to edit `Tomax` and `Tomin`  in the `EEPROM` `0x00h` and `0x01h`

so I simply write this code:

```
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x3B);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x7E);// high byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x90);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();

  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to 01h of EPPROM (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0xB3);//low byte of (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0x6A);//high byte of (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0x89);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
```

But after i make a object reading temperature i find no change in the result so i write this code to display the edited bytes on lcd screen

```
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to read 01h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 25, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 25, Ltrim(display));
  
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to read 00h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 5, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 5, Ltrim(display));
```

they print

147

153

179

106

which is not the bytes i send !!

so where is the problem? Any suggestions?

Attached datasheet
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXVMybLxpEMbtvTb30lneex86iY5orCx/view

i calculated PEC from that site , in case it cause a problem or i calculate it wrong
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

i use mikro C for pic as compiler and pic 18f4620 in case it matters

**FULL code in case it helps more**

```
//###########################SETTING LCD MODULE###################################################
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
// End LCD module connections
//##############################################################################

char display[7];
signed short int lowByte=0;
signed short int highByte=0;
unsigned short int PEC=0;
unsigned int word=0;
unsigned int temp1=0;
double temp=0;

unsigned int redata=0;

void main()
{
  OSCCON.IRCF2=1;
  OSCCON.IRCF1=1;
  OSCCON.IRCF0=0;
  OSCTUNE.PLLEN=1;
  WDTCON.SWDTEN=0;
  ADCON1=62;
  Lcd_Init();
  I2C1_Init(100000);// initialize I2C communication ,100Khz
  Delay_1sec();
  
/*I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);// high byte of  (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x83);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();

  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);// high byte of  (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0xE8);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();*/

  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x3B);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x7E);// high byte of  (To max)
  redata=I2C1_Wr(0x90);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
   while(redata==1){}
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to 01h of EPPROM (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0xB3);//low byte of (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0x6A);//high byte of (To min)
  I2C1_Wr(0x89);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();




  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to read 01h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 25, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 25, Ltrim(display));
  
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to read 00h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 5, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 5, Ltrim(display));
 /*I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x25);//sending command to read 05h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=highByte;
  word<<=8;
  word|=lowByte;
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 5, Ltrim(display));
  lowByte|=0b00110000;
  word=highByte;
  word<<=8;
  word|=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 5, Ltrim(display));
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 25, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 25, Ltrim(display));
/*I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x25);//sending command to read 05h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Wr(lowByte);
  I2C1_Wr(highByte);*/
  
  while(1)
  {
    I2C1_Start();
    I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
    I2C1_Wr(0x07);//sending command to read 07h of RAM
    I2C1_Repeated_Start();
    I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
    lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
    highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
    PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
    I2C1_Stop();
    word=highByte;
    word<<=8;
    word|=lowByte;
    temp=word;
    temp*=0.02;
    temp-=273.15;
    temp1=temp;
    temp1=temp;
  /*Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
    IntToStr(temp1,display);
    Lcd_Out(1, 5, Ltrim(display));
    Lcd_Out(1, 15, "0");*/
    Delay_1sec();
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

After considering what  Adam Lawrence said

i make that code to erase the `EPPROM` and display the existed data after erasing on the LCD

```
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);// high byte of  (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x83);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();

  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to write 00h of EPPROM (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);//low byte of (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0x00);// high byte of  (To max)
  I2C1_Wr(0xE8);//PEC
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x21);//sending command to read 01h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 25, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 25, Ltrim(display));

  
  I2C1_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB4);//sensor Call Address+Write bit as 0
  I2C1_Wr(0x20);//sending command to read 00h of EPPROM
  I2C1_Repeated_Start();
  I2C1_Wr(0xB5);//sensor Call Address+Read bit as 1
  lowByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  highByte=I2C1_Rd(1);
  PEC=I2C1_Rd(0);
  I2C1_Stop();
  Delay_1sec();
  word=lowByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(1, 5, Ltrim(display));
  word=highByte;
  IntToStr(word,display);
  Lcd_Out(2, 5, Ltrim(display));
```

i got this on LCD respectively

147

153

0

0

so what is wrong with `00H cell` of `EPPROM` or what is wrong with me ?!
The pieces of code are identical !! just change the addresses , so why one erase and the other one not!

**EDIT 2**

i found the solution , the point is to erase or write twice in the `00h` EPPROM location to make the result happen , i dont know why but it works and it is displayed on LCD correctly . can anyone enlighten us with the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SMBus application note](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J171/MLX90614_SMBus.pdf) says you must erase before writing new values. Example code from the datasheet is posted below.

> In  Application  mode  only  9  cells  are  accessible  for  writing.  An  attempt  to  write  not  accessible EEPROM cell results in no change.  Before writing an erasing operation must be done. An erasing operation is just a writing of zeros in an EEPROM cell. After a/an writing/erasing 5ms are need the new value to be written/erased. After writing it is strongly recommended that the device is restarted by  turning off/on the power supply or by putting the sensor in/out sleep.
>
> An Erasing of the EEPROM address 0x0E (SMBus Address)
>
> 1. Send START bit
> 2. Send Slave Address (0x00* for example) + Rd-Wr bit**
> 3. Send Command (0b001x_xxxx + 0b0000_1110 -> 0b0010_1110)
> 4. Send Low data 0x00
> 5. Send High data 0x00
> 6. Send PEC 0x6F
> 7. Send STOP bit
> 8. Wait 5ms (this time is need the cell to be erased)

Comment: Thank you for contribution i consider it,i start now to erase first 
after erasing i display the new content on the LCD before assigning the new values

Comment: Check the edit please

Comment: and after checking i will be waiting for your reply

Comment: Did you see the line: "After writing it is strongly recommended that the device is restarted by turning off/on the power supply or by putting the sensor in/out sleep"? Did you try this?

Comment: yes sure 
the result on LCD is after restarting the power

Comment: check section "EDIT  2"

in my question above to see the last updates i reached

Comment: You aren't following the datasheet recommendation of power-cycling or going into/outo of sleep mode after a write. The behaviour of the device in this mode is undefined. Luckily you found a workaround but it may not work 100% for all devices in all conditions. You really should modify your code to match what the manufacturer says. If you were to ask them for help right now, all they would say to you is "follow the datasheet".

Comment: You mean that after EACH write or erase operation i should turn the pow off then on ?

Comment: My interpretation of the datasheet is that you should not expect to read back what was written without performing the power/cycle or sleep/awake operation. I don't think it's critical to perform it after every write, but certainly important to perform it before attempting the readback.